# Why is PrintStream class reference  declared as a static variable in System class in java?

Tags: java, printstream

Can I use a `PrintStream`'s `println()` method without involving the `System` class?

Comment: (a) Your actual question has nothing to do with your title. Which question do you want answered? (b) Did you consider *trying* it?

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely - `System.out` and `System.err` are just the `PrintStream` values associated with standard out and standard error.

You can create a `PrintStream` from any `OutputStream`, or just by giving a filename. However, it will always use the system default encoding.

Prefer [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), which will wrap an arbitrary `Writer`. However, this will *still* suppress `IOException` from being thrown, which doesn't seem a good idea to me.

Prefer [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

```
BufferedWriter wrapper = new BufferedWriter(writer);
try {
    wrapper.write(...);
    wrapper.newLine();
} finally {
    wrapper.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The System class doesn't "*reference the PrintStream class*". It has two static fields of type PrintStream: `out` and `err`. So if you want to write to the out stream, you use `System.out`. If you want to write to the err stream, you use `System.err`. If you want to write to another PrintStream, you construct one by yourself: `new PrintStream(...)`.

Comment: -1. Make up your mind. Either it doesn't reference the PrintStream class *or* it has two static variables of that type. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: "Referencing a class" doesn't mean anything. Having a static field of a given type means something.

Comment: References to other classes are what the class loader resolves when it loads a class. I don't find this meaningless in the slightest.